# not converting mongodb document id to a pojo field

Tags: java, mongodb, gson

I am retrieving some document from mongodb and then converting that document to json. The resulting json is as follows

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "60f84fc822818919d59e3ad2"}, "metadata": [{"country": "USA", "authors": [{"author": "Ayn Rand", "books": [{"name": "The Fountainhead", "code": "TFH"}]}]}]}
```

I created a POJO to parse it everything else is getting parsed properly but the "_id" part is not getting parsed. Any suggestions why its not getting parsed?

Below are my POJOs

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class MetadataCollection {
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private MetadataId id;

    private List<Metadata> metadata;

    public MetadataId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(MetadataId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Metadata> getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setMetadata(List<Metadata> metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }
}
```

and

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class MetadataId {
    @JsonProperty("$oid")
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I tried using "id", "@Id", "$oid" and some suggestion from other answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66415106/mongodb-java-pojo-not-returning-id). The method I am using is as follows

```
public List<MetadataCollection> getAuthorsMetadata() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MongoCollection<Document> metadataCollection = mDatabase.getCollection("authors_metadata");
        MongoCursor<Document> findIterableDocuments = metadataCollection.find().cursor();

        List<MetadataCollection> returnMetadata = new ArrayList<>();
        while (findIterableDocuments.hasNext()) {
            Document currentDocument = findIterableDocuments.next();

            String jsonString = currentDocument.toJson();

            MetadataCollection metadata = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MetadataCollection.class);

            returnMetadata.add(metadata);
        }
        mongoClient.close();
        return returnMetadata;
    }
```

Comment: What if you use a Gson annotation, `@SerializedName`, and not the annotation obviously coming from a foreign library, `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`?

Comment: But this foreign library is working fine for Metadata class.

Comment: So what? 1) Why are you using two libraries doing the same? 2) Why using the library B if the library A is working fine? 3) Why not adding `@SerializedName` so that two libraries could work together? 4) Or why not using Jackson instead of Gson just because you put the JsonProperty annotation? 5) Or why not implementing a Gson type adapter that would recognize the JsonProperty annotation if you must (I doubt) use Gson? These questions are rhetorical enough and trivial enough.

Comment: It worked, Thanks. If you would like to formalize it as an answer then it would help others as well.